# @AttributeOverride to add column information

Tags: java, jpa

Is there any way to *add* (**not replace**) column information using @AttributeOverride or another annotation?

I'm trying to do the following:

```
@Embeddable
class SomeEmbeddable {

    @Column(length = 32)
    private String myField;

}

@Entity
class SomeEntity {

    @AttributeOverride(name = "myField", column = @Column(nullable = false))
    private SomeEmbeddable myEmbeddableField;

}
```

I want myEmbeddableField to have **both** nullable = false and length = 32, but of course, the @AttributeOverride annotation replaces all the column constraints. Is there any workaround other than setting length = 32 in the SomeEntity class?

Thanks